# Fast enumeration over nil object

Tags: objective-c, fast-enumeration

What should happen here? Is it safe?

```
NSArray *nullArray=nil;
for (id obj in nullArray) {
  // blah
}
```

More specifically, do I have to do this:

```
NSArray *array=[thing methodThatMightReturnNil];
if (array) {
  for (id obj in array) {
    // blah
  }
}
```

or is this fine?:

```
for (id obj in [thing methodThatMightReturnNil]) {
  // blah
}
```

Comment: @JeremyP: I almost said that myself, but it's nice to know not only that it happens to work, but that it works by design, there are implementation-independent reasons it works, and it's likely to continue to work in future versions of OS X.

Comment: @JeremyP Seriously. I already did that before I asked the question, and it worked with no errors. But it proves nothing because it could have been a fluke. I was looking for the theory behind it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nothing will happen. A for-in loop uses the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol to iterate over the elements in a collection, so you're essentially sending a message to `nil` which is safe in Objective-C.

Answer (score 51):

Fast enumeration is implemented through the method `- countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:`, which returns 0 to signal the end of the loop. Since `nil` returns `0` for any method, your loop should never execute. (So it's safe.)